# Python/Django - Where do I have to make methods that perform like DML?

Tags: python, django, database, standards

'Methods that perform like DML' means methods that change data in the database.
Is there a standard or guideline for that?

Below are my own guesses.

1. Collect all functions in file of which name is like 'data_access.py'
2. Contain functions in each class of models.py
3. There is no standard. No one will blame even if I make them in views.py
4. Above all are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common philosophy in Django is "fat models, thin views", so preferably you would put as much of this DML functionality as functions on your model classes. Since `models.py` already defines the structure of your data, it makes sense to put functions that manipulate your data in the same file as much as possible.

Comment: Oho, thanks. I'll keep in mind "fat models, thin views".